# Generate custom initramfs image with additional configuration files

Tags: debian, initrd, initramfs

I would like to create an initramfs image for Debian Stretch which includes additional configuration files (say `/etc/a.conf`).

What do I have to do prior to running `mkinitramfs -o initrd.img` in order for the image to include such files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have chosen to do this with an initramfs hook for this ensures (if I understand correctly) that the change will also persist across future kernel upgrades. The hook takes the form of a script `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/copy_etc` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ "$1" = "prereqs" ]; then exit 0; fi
. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

cp /etc/a.conf $DESTDIR/etc/a.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

The tool you want for modifying the initrd/initramfs is called [cpio](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cpio). You can find a bunch of tutorials on this out on the internet, now that you know what to look for. Here's a quick example:

```
mkdir initrd-tmp
cd initrd-tmp
lzma -dc -S .lz /mnt/casper/initrd.lz | cpio -id
```

And then when done:

```
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ~/new-initrd.lz
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd

Note that a fun property of cpio archives is that you can simply append to them and later files overwrite earlier files—probably due to their heritage as a file system for tape archival. So if you don't want the hassle of actually unpacking the whole archive (especially as it may require root to create paths like `/proc`), you can simply append your customization files to it. See:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetbootFirmware#Example_.231:_add_debs_from_firmware.cpio.gz

Comment: So if I understand correctly what you are doing here is not building a new initramfs image from scratch (while adding `/etc/a.conf` presumably with a `mkinitramfs` hook), but unpacking the existing image, adding only `/etc/a.conf` to the unpacked version, and packaging it again. Correct?

Comment: @rookie099 Yes, that's correct. This answer is geared more toward customizing the installation/live environment, which tends to be a one-off thing (or implemented in whatever CI process generates your customized installer). If you need ongoing customization, then yes, use the mkinitramfs hook.